# Como funciona o cache em html5?

Tags: html5, cache

Tenho uma webapp e gostaria que ela tivesse um cache para não ficar acessando toda hora.
Minha webapp se constitui em uma index.html que faz parse em outros sites.
Então toda vez que o webapp é aberto ele carrega e faz o processo de parse no site.

Como eu poderia aplicar um cache para melhorar a usabilidade?

segue o codigo que carrega no head:

```
<head>
 <script src="js/jquery-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        // O charset do site original é "iso-8859-1", isso arruma erros:
        $.ajaxSetup({
            'beforeSend': function(xhr) {
                xhr.overrideMimeType('text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
            },
        });

        $.ajax('http://www.corsproxy.com/m.jcnet.com.br/cinema/')
                .done(function(data) {
                    var dom = $(data);

                    $('output').empty();

                    // O site é bem desorganizado, procurar dados nele
                    // é um tanto complicado, mas possível:
                    dom.find('.descricao').each(function() {
                        var item = $(this);

                        // Limpa dados desnecessários:
                        item.find('.font12').remove();

                        // Adiciona o título:
                        $('<h2>', {text: item.prev().find('strong').text()})
                                .appendTo('output');

                        // Adiciona a imagem:
                        item.find('td.fontPreto img').first().appendTo('output');

                         $('<br>').appendTo('output');

                        // Adiciona dados do filme:
                        item.find('p').appendTo('output');

                        $('<br>').appendTo('output');
                    });
                })
                .fail(function(error) {
                    $('output').insertBefore('<b>É um erro, Bino.</b>')
                });
                //Agradecimentos ao user  @Gustavo Rodrigues, por ter feito essa belezinha e me explicado como funciona >:)
    </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

Com HTML 5 é possível fazer o cache de uma página completa ou fazer uso de um arquivo `CACHE MANIFEST` para tal.

Para o navegador criar o cache somente da página, sua tag HTML deverá estar assim:

`<html manifest="exemplo.appcache">`

Para criar um cache de mais de um arquivo (seu script jquery por exemplo), é necessário criar um arquivo `CACHE MANIFEST` no seu servidor e na propriedade `manifest` da tag `<html>` apontar a URL completa desse arquivo, após habilitar o mime-type `text/cache-manifest` no seu servidor.

Mais informações consulte as referências abaixo:

- [Guia Básico sobre o uso do Cache do Aplicativo](https://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)
- [Offline Web applications - HTML 5<sup>en</sup>](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/offline.html)

Comment: tem algum exemplo que eu possa ver? Estou utilizando isso no phonegap o html não há um servidor. por exemplo eu adiciono no html o manifest e aponto para um arquivo cache. Mas se caso houver uma conexão ele vai se conectar primeiro e depois pegar do cache? tem algum timeout?