# Existe alguma maneira de limpar cache no navegador do cliente?

Tags: php, javascript, cdn

Por exemplo, tenho meu site e fiz uma modificação, mas ela ainda não foi aplicada no navegador do cliente. Existe algum jeito de eu rodar essa limpeza de cache no navegador do cliente? Com PHP, JavaScript talvez?

Num site que estou trabalhando, possui o cache CDN, mas percebi que mesmo eu limpando o cache CDN do site, "não adianta", pôs a mudança so vai ser vista na tela do cliente, se ele limpar o cache do navegador dele.

Comment: Tem um jeito que eu uso e funciona, na hora de carregar o JS ou CSS, no final do arquivo colocar um `? + time()`, vai ficar assim: meuarquivo.css?10312000114

Comment: Não entendi Everson, poderia explicar?

Comment: Dependendo do CDN pode ficar em cache por meses. Geralmente na DOC há explicações sobre os parâmetros do arquivo para evitar a requisição em cache. Já deu uma olhada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar nomes dinâmicos para os arquivos, assim o navegador vai forçar o download.

> Exemplo:

```
<script src="https://cdn.meucdn.com/js/meu-arquivo.js?v=<?php echo $version_js; ?>"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.meucdn.com/css/meu-arquivo.css?v=<?php echo $version_css; ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Uma boa prática é você versionar o seu arquivo JS e baixar ele somente quando houver alterações, ai é só mudar o valor da variável `$version` que vai forçar o download do arquivo, mas caso deseja forçar o download sempre você pode definir a variável `$version = time();`, porém acho que vai forçar muito o seu servidor em caso de muitos acessos.

Comment: Por exemplo, tem como eu fazer isso com CSS? forçar o cliente a "baixar ele somente quando houver alterações"

Comment: Sim seguindo o mesmo esquema.

Comment: Editei a resposta veja se te ajuda

Comment: "porém acho que vai forçar muito o seu servidor em caso de muitos acessos." acho que então melhor não usar esse método, tem 1 milhão e 200mil acessos por mês, talvez vá prejudicar o site.

Comment: Por exemplo, é Magento, ele tem o botão no painel "LIMPAR CACHE CDN", eu limpo esse cache, mas parece que as alterações com CSS só são aplicadas no navegador do CLIENTE quando: Ou o mesmo nunca visitou o site ou se o mesmo limpar o cache do navegador.

Comment: Acredito que seja gerado o arquivo novamente, mas pode fazer um teste provavelmente o arquivo js e css ou tem um versionamento ou então ele gera um arquivo com outro nome.. No seu caso o botão limpar cache/cdn poderia dar um update em uma coluna e o seu ?v= poderia recuperar esse valor.

Comment: Pode usar esse método sim, só não use o método time() na variável de controle de versão ... implemente um controle para mudar a versão quando vc desejar... isso pode ser feito criando uma coluna no banco ai vc resgata esse valor e quando quiser limpar dá um update mudando a versão

Comment: Verdade @HENRIQUELOBO mas vale lembrar que é um especificação do HMTL 5.

Comment: Usando o CACHE MANIFEST você consegue resolver seu problema, dê uma olhada nessa questão:                                                                    
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9009/como-funciona-o-cache-em-html5/9040#9040

Answer (score 0):

Se o servidor que hospeda teu site é linux, você pode definir o tempo de cache no arquivo de configuração .htaccess:

```
Header unset Pragma
FileETag None
Header unset ETag

# 1 Ano (limitado a ficheiro media)
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|mp3|mp4)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2010 20:00:00 GMT"
Header unset Last-Modified 
</FilesMatch>

# 2 Horas (limitado a ficheiro conteúdos)
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|xml|txt|xsl)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

# Em cache para sempre (scripts e folhas de estilo)
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2010 20:00:00 GMT"
Header unset Last-Modified
</FilesMatch>
```

Retirei deste post [Como forçar a limpeza de cache nos navegadores dos meus visitantes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21724/como-for%C3%A7ar-a-limpeza-de-cache-nos-navegadores-dos-meus-visitantes)